# How to export a __interface derived class in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to export a class type that derives from a __interface(only available for Visual c++),which aiming to create c#-like inteface-oriented experience.

```
//This wiil be defined in a "Famous.h"
__interface IFoo {
int GetNum();
};

//And this is my implementation.

#include "...Famous.h"
class FooImpl : public IFoo
{
public:
    FooImpl(int a);
private:
    int a;
};

FooImpl::FooImpl(int a)
{
this->a = a;
}
```

The problem is ,How could I export the 'FoolImpl' type to use it as follows in another project without refrencing the project directly.I tried dllexport,and tons of errors make me exthausted :(.

```
#include "..Impl.h"
#include "..Famous.h"
void main(){
    IFoo* foo = new FooImpl(2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is no point in exporting an interface, it has no implementation.  You simply put the declaration in a .h file that you #include in both projects.  Depending on the object model, you normally also need to expose the factory function.  The one you call in the client code instead of trying to instantiate FooImpl.  It does very little, just new FooImpl and returns the interface pointer.  You can export FooImpl but then there is no point in using an interface anymore.

Comment: @Hans Passant,Thanks for your suggestions,trying to export it by objectd-oriented way as easy as on c#-way, I've just solve this by replacing __interface with pure virtual class and applied dllexport :).

Answer (score 0):

Considering of there's no interface in c++,I replaced the __interface with pure virtual class.

```
//This wiil be defined in a "Famous.h"
#ifdef FAMOUS_EXPORTS
#define XYZAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define XYZAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class XYZAPI IFoo {
 virual int GetNum() = 0;//void type also valid.
};

//And this is my implementation(Impl.h).
#ifdef IMPL_EXPORTS
#define XYZAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define XYZAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#include "...Famous.h"
class XYZAPI  FooImpl : public IFoo
{
public:
    FooImpl(int a);
private:
    int a;
};

FooImpl::FooImpl(int a)
{
    this->a = a;
}
```

And this is my invocation.

```
#include "..Impl.h"
#include "..Famous.h"
void main(){
    IFoo* foo = new FooImpl(2);
    ...
}
```